# Heroku automatic deploys not doing anything

Tags: github, heroku

I'm guess I'm missing something here. I enabled Automatic Deploys on Heroku, and it's connected to my GitHub repo. All looks good on Deploy page:

[image]

However when I push changes to `main` nothing happens. I have to go and manually click "Deploy Branch" in order to deploy... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

PS If I push through `heroku` (i.e. `git push heroku main`) it deploys the branch, but I thought the automatic deploys feature allows me to push to git without specifying `heroku`.

Comment: "You can now change your main deploy branch from "master" to "main" for both manual and automatic deploys, please follow the instructions here." Did you follow the article: https://help.heroku.com/O0EXQZTA/how-do-i-switch-branches-from-master-to-main ? You need to delete the master branch from the heroku git and then deploy from the main branch. Then it will pick the main branch.

Comment: @TinNguyen where do I run `git checkout -b main`? If I run it in my main folder, I get `fatal: A branch named 'main' already exists.`.